# Can't run a giraph SimpleInDegreeCountComputation

Tags: apache, giraph

I'm trying to run the SimpleInDegreeCountComputation example included with Giraph. My approach is as follows:

SimpleInDegreeCountComputation.java:

```
    public class SimpleInDegreeCountComputation extends BasicComputation
              <LongWritable, LongWritable, DoubleWritable, DoubleWritable> {
    .......
```

I then try running it like so:

```
    hadoop jar /path-to-giraph-folder/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.1.0- 
    SNAPSHOT-for-hadoop-1.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
    org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner  
    org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleInDegreeCountComputation 
    -vif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat 
    -vip /path-to-input-file 
    -vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat 
    -op /path-to-output-file -w 1
```

The result is the following:

```
    14/05/18 18:58:40 INFO utils.ConfigurationUtils: No edge input format specified. 
    Ensure your InputFormat does not require one.
    14/05/18 18:58:40 INFO utils.ConfigurationUtils: No edge output format specified.  
    Ensure your OutputFormat does not require one.
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: checkClassTypes: vertex  
    value types not assignable, computation - class org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable,   
    VertexInputFormat - class org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable
at org.apache.giraph.job.GiraphConfigurationValidator.checkAssignable(GiraphConfigurationValidator.java:381)
at org.apache.giraph.job.GiraphConfigurationValidator.verifyVertexInputFormatGenericTypes(GiraphConfigurationValidator.java:228)
at org.apache.giraph.job.GiraphConfigurationValidator.validateConfiguration(GiraphConfigurationValidator.java:141)
at org.apache.giraph.utils.ConfigurationUtils.parseArgs(ConfigurationUtils.java:214)
at org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner.run(GiraphRunner.java:74)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
at org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner.main(GiraphRunner.java:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. If anyone can point me in the right direction, or link to a resource that explains an easier way of what I'm trying to do, I'd greatly appreciate it! I think that the problem may be the wrong formats (-vif).
The input file I'm using is the following:

```
    [0,0,[[1,5],[2,9]]]
    [1,0,[[0,5],[3,3]]]
    [2,0,[[0,9],[3,3],[4,3]]]
    [3,0,[[1,3],[2,3],[4,2]]]
    [4,0,[[2,3],[3,3]]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the definition of the compute and vertex-input classes, it seems that the `JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat` isn't compatible with `SimpleInDegreeCountComputation`

[SimpleInDegreeCountComputation](https://github.com/apache/giraph/blob/trunk/giraph-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/giraph/examples/SimpleInDegreeCountComputation.java):

```
public class SimpleInDegreeCountComputation extends BasicComputation<
    LongWritable, LongWritable, DoubleWritable, DoubleWritable> {
```

[BasicComputation](https://github.com/apache/giraph/blob/trunk/giraph-core/src/main/java/org/apache/giraph/graph/BasicComputation.java):

```
/**
 * Computation in which both incoming and outgoing message types are the same.
 *
 * @param <I> Vertex id
 * @param <V> Vertex data
 * @param <E> Edge data
 * @param <M> Message type
 */
public abstract class BasicComputation<I extends WritableComparable,
    V extends Writable, E extends Writable, M extends Writable>
    extends AbstractComputation<I, V, E, M, M> {
}
```

You can see that:

- Vertex id is of Type `LongWritable`
- Vertex data is of Type `LongWritable`
- Edge data is of Type `DoubleWritable`

... on the other hand the InputFormat you are trying to use ...

[JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat](https://github.com/apache/giraph/blob/trunk/giraph-core/src/main/java/org/apache/giraph/io/formats/JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat.java):

```
public class JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat extends
    TextVertexInputFormat<LongWritable, DoubleWritable, FloatWritable> {
```

[TextVertexInputFormat](https://github.com/apache/giraph/blob/trunk/giraph-core/src/main/java/org/apache/giraph/io/formats/TextVertexInputFormat.java):

```
/**
 * Abstract class that users should subclass to use their own text based
 * vertex input format.
 *
 * @param <I> Vertex index value
 * @param <V> Vertex value
 * @param <E> Edge value
 */
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public abstract class TextVertexInputFormat<I extends WritableComparable,
    V extends Writable, E extends Writable>
    extends VertexInputFormat<I, V, E> {
```

You can see that:

- Vertex id is of Type `LongWritable`
- Vertex data is of Type `DoubleWritable`
- Edge data is of Type `FloatWritable`

---

Since it's `LongWritable`, `DoubleWritable` and `FloatWritable` and not `Long`, `Double` and `Float` - those types cannot be converted automatically.

I couldn't find any InputFormat you could use instead, so you'll either need to modify the existing `JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat` or modify the algorithm to use `NullWritable` for the Edge data type. I don't see anywhere the Edge-data to be used so it can as well be null. In this case, you can use [LongLongNullTextInputFormat](https://github.com/apache/giraph/blob/trunk/giraph-core/src/main/java/org/apache/giraph/io/formats/LongLongNullTextInputFormat.java).

Comment: Hi zahorak! Thank you for the answer. I tried to do so, but now the problem is to create a new jar that contains a modified file. I'm not sure how to do that. I unpacked  giraph-examples-1.1.0- 
    SNAPSHOT-for-hadoop-1.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar to get a look how it is made. But i'm not still able no create a correct jar file because I don't have all files that are necessary (that are contained in giraph-examples-1.1.0- 
    SNAPSHOT-for-hadoop-1.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar ). Any suggestions?

Comment: all my code which I wrote in giraph, I just did inside the giraph-examples. Just check out from github https://github.com/apache/giraph and edit it, afterwards run `mvn clean install -DskipTests` and you should get all the jars you need. https://github.com/pgrm/giraph is my repository with my changes to giraph-examples, to be able to run my code.

Comment: Thank you zahorak. So according to your suggestions my solution was:
1) get the code from github
2) modify the file SimpleInDegreeCountComputation
3) create the jars with mvn install
Now it works :))

Comment: Step 4) could be to send a pull request back, so that others wouldn't have this issue anymore (but I'm not sure if they'll accept it)